# Dynamanically add column(s) and insert values into a Sqlite TABLE from json objects

Tags: python, sql, json, database, sqlite

I am using the Python `tweepy` library to scrap and collect tweet data for a research purpose. Specifically is use `tweepy.StreamingClient` class to get tweet the from stream. Returned data is `json` object whose elements depends on the data fields available with retrieved tweet post.

So for example, at one time I received `json` object with few elements like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "1556031969062010881",
    "created_at": "2022-08-18T01:51:03.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "place_id": "006c6743642cb09c"
    },
    "id": "1560081812604469248",
    "text": "Some text ..."
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560077018183630848",
      "tag": "some-key-words"
    }
  ]
}
```

And some time, returned object with expanded elements like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "1118585113657389059",
    "created_at": "2022-08-18T01:55:05.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "place_id": "00611f1548c7bdef"
    },
    "id": "1560082826153828357",
    "referenced_tweets": [
      {
        "type": "replied_to",
        "id": "1559833610697539585"
      }
    ],
    "text": "hhh personality"
  },
  "includes": {
    "tweets": [
      {
        "author_id": "1462820862969716746",
        "created_at": "2022-08-17T09:24:47.000Z",
        "geo": {},
        "id": "1559833610697539585",
        "text": "What do men like in a woman?"
      }
    ]
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560077018183630848",
      "tag": "some-key-words"
    }
  ]
}
```

At even a more complex `json` object with nested elements at times like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "1461871206425108480",
    "created_at": "2022-08-17T23:19:14.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1094,
          51.5141
        ]
      },
      "place_id": "3eb2c704fe8a50cb"
    },
    "id": "1560043605762392066",
    "text": "#bitemoji #me #thinkingaboutmydeceasedKoreanGrandmother #ALWAYS #DAILY #AMEN @ London, United Kingdom "
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560042248007458817",
      "tag": "some-key-words"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am interested in elements of the `data`, and `matching_rules` groups, the latter contains 2-elements only, but former (`data`) group element(s) can change or expand. For example the `geo` element, which is of particular interest in this work, it has:

```
"geo": {
      "place_id": "some-value"
    },
```

in the first and second returned objects, but then in 3rd object, it is expanded like so:

```
"geo": {
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1094,
          51.5141
        ]
      },
      "place_id": "3eb2c704fe8a50cb"
    },
```

So we have to create 2-new columns to store the `type": "Point",` and `"coordinates": [-0.1094,51.5141]` values.

Yet, we can see in the second object, another `geo` element in the `"includes"` group. This completely not required, but could potentially "confuse" our searches.

How can I have dynamically store add column and an initially "narrow" starting table and insert values in this scenario?

I have used `sqlite` to insert values from sensors an IoT research where I used the syntax:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("db-name.db")

while True:
    # values received
    query = "INSERT INTO table_name(columns-names) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    data = (variable)
    cur = con.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
con.close()
```

However, in this case, the dynamic growth in table columns and/or changing values of some elements (e.g. `geo` confuses me the more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can alter tables dynamically, treating columns in the same way as rows is not a good idea. You can use one of the following options.

1. Save the whole JSON in a single field and use SQLite's JSON library.
2. If you can define fields you are mostly interested in, you can use #1 with fixed generated columns defined at start and holding extracted values of interest.
3. If you can define a finite amount of columns for all potential fields of interests, you can use a fixed schema and store for each tweet just the available fields.
4. Perhaps, you should not be using a relational db to start with. Based on your data definition, you may want to use a document store instead.

Comment: I will go with 1, and later create tables to be populated using queries from the raw data table if that's possible. Let me check with the SQLITE's JSON library functionalities.